# How does Captain America pick up his shield so easily when it's lying with the convex side facing up?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, captain-america-the-winter-soldier

We saw this happening in the bridge fight scene in the movie *Captain America: The Winter Soldier* just after Steve jumped out of the bus when the machine gunner was trying to shoot him.

The question doesn't have to do anything with the properties of vibranium, just the fact that if a curved plate lies on a flat surface, with the convex side facing up, it's difficult to pick it up.

One can, obviously do it after some efforts, maybe with the help of finger nails, but the fact that Steve picked up the shield instantly is a little difficult for me to digest.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  You should take the [tour] and join us!

Comment: I don't understand the question, in that, is there any reason to think one *couldn't* do this? Is the question based on the nature of vibranium, or simply the convex shape of the shield in relation to a flat surface, etc...?

Comment: Also, the shield isn't immune to *friction* just vibrations/enrgy absorbtion (at least as far as I understand it generally).

Comment: Hi. Do you think there's an SF element to this?  Otherwise, it's just design.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The shield is lying on a crack in the surface of the road. Anyone (regardless of their superpowers) could easily put their fingers under it and lift it up.

[image: The shield lying on the road with an arrow pointing out the cracks underneath it leaving a gap so it is not flush to the floor]

as you can see...

[image: A close up of Steve's arm picking up the shiled off the road; his fingers curl under the shield in the cracks to pick it up]

Comment: Considering this particular case as a sheer coincidence, shouldn't he be facing problems at times when the shield lies on an undamaged flat surface? The shield is purely symmetrical. There's no chance he could do that had it been a perfect flat surface.

Comment: @SYnc - It also has magnetic properties and I assume he's practiced picking it up off the floor using his arm magnet when it''s face down,